# enabling aspectj with environment variables

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj

How can we enable/disable an aspect using environment variables?

I know it is possible to enable/disable aspectj in spring boot application using following properties

```yaml
spring:
  aop:
    auto: true
```

Or:

```yaml
spring.aop.auto=true
```

And removing `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, but this stops all of our other aspects / joins.

This is the one I want to disable, how do I do it

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(someAnnotation)")
    public Object doSomething(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, SomeAnnotation sa) throws Throwable {
        // ...
    }

    //others
}
```

Comment: srry was on holidays xD, with no access to code... I did indeed refactor the code and moved it to a separate class back then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to dynamically deactivate a single advice inside an aspect class, you can use an `if()` pointcut.

If you want to completely disable an aspect (or any other Spring bean or component) based on conditions like e.g. a property in `application.config`, have a look at `@Conditional` and its special cases `@ConditionalOn*`. For example:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "org.acme.myapp", name = "aspect_active")
public class SomeAspect {
  // ...
}
```

Something like this in `application.config` would deactivate the aspect:

```yaml
org.acme.myapp.aspect_active=false
```

The aspect would also be inactive if there was no such property in the application config at all. If you rather want to default to an active aspect, just use

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "org.acme.myapp", name = "aspect_active", matchIfMissing = true)
```

You can further fine-tune the behaviour as described in the javadoc.

See also:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditional-annotations
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty

---

**Update:**

> In order to dynamically deactivate a single advice inside an aspect class, you can use an `if()` pointcut.

Oops, sorry, I am a native AspectJ user and forgot that Spring AOP does not support the `if()` pointcut designator. So probably the best you can do is an `if` expression at the beginning of your advice, depending on a `@Value` property.

```java
@Value("${org.acme.myapp.advice_active:false}")
private boolean adviceActive;

@Around("@annotation(someAnnotation)")
public Object doSomething(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, SomeAnnotation sa) throws Throwable {
  // Skip advice logic if inactive, simply proceed and return original result
  if (!adviceActive)
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  
  // Regular advice logic if active
  System.out.println(joinPoint);
  // Either also proceed or do whatever else is the custom advice logic, e.g.
  //   - manipulate method arguments,
  //   - manipulate original return value,
  //   - skip proceeding to the original method altogether and return something else.
  return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Of course, you can also use my original solution and just factor out the advice you wish to deactivate into a separate aspect class, if you need that kind of granularity. That would be less hassle, and the advice method code would be more readable.

Comment: hi @kriegaex I am using ```@ConditionalOnExpression("${what.ever.here:false}")```at the moment, but it disable the whole class. can you direct me to a working if() example please ?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I am a native AspectJ user and forgot that Spring AOP does not support the `if()` pointcut designator. So probably the best you can do is an `if` expression at the beginning of your advice, depending on a `@Value` property. Please see my updated answer.